# react doesn't work on android kitkat 4.4.4 webview

Tags: reactjs

i made an application with react, it works fine in chrome but when i try to run it with a browser that has a kiosk option, i get "Uncaught ReferenceError: Map is not defined".
i tried the solution provided in the documentation but still no success, so i made another application just for test and i got this error : "SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode".

first project created with "react": "^16.8.6",
second project created with "react": "^16.9.0",

device is Samsung Galaxy Tab E.

browser is kiosk browser lockdown :
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.procoit.kioskbrowser&hl=en

this is the solution i've tried but didn't work :  https://reactjs.org/docs/javascript-environment-requirements.html

Comment: You shouldn't be running a kiosk on an unsupported version of Android to begin with.

Comment: Either way, we'll need to know more about how you're building your application. If you are using Babel with `babel-preset-env`, you should be able to simply add `android 4.4` into your Browserslist configuration.

Comment: i am building it by using create-react-app